# Readonly input text appears unlocked while the page is loading

Tags: jquery, profiling

I need help with a code for locking editing an input of type text in the profile page of Wordpress.

I added the following code:

```
(function(){
    $("#email").attr("readonly","readonly");
});
```

But while the page is loading, the field appears unlocked, and if the user press 'Esc', the page loading is stopped and he can edit the field.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: use jQuery instead $ [check it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the reply, but the hint below seems to be more efficient and important, because with the simple technique of 'inspect element' of Chrome Browser the user can edit the field by removing the rule 'readonly'. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting an input to "read only" by whatever means, Javascript or PHP generated or hard-coded markup, has zero security value. It is trivial to remove that "lock" with FireBug or the Web Developer extension, and I am sure others as well. What you are doing is cosmetic at best.

If you want to prevent the user's email address from being changed you will have to catch the form submission with (probably the `personal_options_update` and/or `edit_user_profile_update` hooks and force the email to remain the same as whatever is already in the database. Something like this:

```
function lock_user_email_wpse_100146($userid) {
  $user = get_userdata($userid);
  if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $_POST['email'] = $user->user_email;
  }
}
add_action('personal_options_update','lock_user_email_wpse_100146');
```

I caution you against doing that, as it *prevents users from changing their email addresses*, and people do change email addresses. If you do this and someone changes address that person is no longer able to reset their password. It is a very unfriendly thing to meddle with.

Comment: Hello, thank for the reply.

Really this method is not safe. But it is a necessity unique because it is a site with registration of students and they should use the mail provided by the University.

Thank you so very much for your help, I will test even the Hook you provided.

Comment: What method isn't safe? Yours or mine? I agree that in very special circumstances "locking" the email could be justified.

Comment: Sorry if I expressed myself badly, I meant that using the 'readonly' jQuery is not safe because with the simple 'inspect element' in Chrome Browser the user can disable the 'readonly' and edit the field.

I'll use the Hook you posted. I tested it and it worked.

Thnaks.